# Spinner issue on samsung galaxy s3

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Im using samsung galaxy s3 to test my application, I have three edittext and one spinner. whenever i click the spinner, it clears the edittext value of three edittext, and after clicking item from the spinner, i get the valuo of edit text.
For below version of android, spinner will display like dialog, covers maximum screen. But in the Android 4.0, its like drop down, and its also clears the edittext data.

How to fix this issue?

```
    spRejectionCode = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spRejection);     
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterNo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,Constants.rejectioncode);
    adapterNo.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spRejectionCode.setAdapter(adapterNo);
```

Comment: Can you post a code so we could analyze it?

Comment: It would be better if you show your code (where problem is occuring )

Comment: see my edit, why down vote for this question?

Comment: And im not doing anything in onItemClick Listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the issue , in earlier version the spinner looks like dialog and now in android 4.0 onwards it looks like drop down , so don't worry about the look and feel of spinner.

Comment: ya, spinner looks good, i want to know why it clears the edittext values?

Comment: @kumaand can you please show your onItemClick Listener code ?

Comment: just get the value from spinner, append it. not doing anything in edittext.